# Node.js best practices for C#.net developers

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I am new to Node.js coming from a C#.net background.  When coding in .net, I was use to using several of the design patterns to organize my code, service layer, repository, etc.  When I needed to add logic that spanned multiple models, I could use services for this as well.  Moving to Node.js and reviewing examples and sample code, etc. I do not see a lot of utilization of service layer, repositories, etc.  What are some of the recommended practices for the following:

1. Code organization and structure, especially for apps rich in business logic?
2. How to handle logic that spans multiple models?
3. What are some good tutorials and sample code sites that demonstrate some good project and code structure with items (1 and (2 in mind?

.net comes with a lot of recommended approaches, practices, patterns and coding structure techniques that are actually very good recommendations.  Sites like [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net), etc. provide pretty good articles, etc. for these recommendations.

I am having trouble finding a consistent approach reviewing Node.js examples.

Comment: I don't either.  The issues are that coming from a structured background, I just want to make sure I am following the best practices using node.js.  I could also see where these resources would be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like you I have come from C#/.NET to Node.js and found that much of what I thought was good practise in C# to be less than useful in Node.js.

Domain Driven Design (DDD) is not often discussed in a Node.js setting since DDD is usually associated with Object Oriented Design and Javascript is not an OO language (even though Javascript has prototype-based inheritance, a lot of OO patterns simply don't translate well to Javascript).

Instead we see more Microservice architectures whereby we break large domains down into smaller, decoupled services which perform one business function well. Node.js is perfect for these sorts of lightweight HTTP services.

The interesting thing I have found is that after trying a Microservices approach over DDD I actually find it much easier to implement and easier to keep things decoupled along appropriate lines. In fact when I go back to C# I find myself applying a Microservices approach there too.

In terms of patterns, abstracting away persistence is still an very good idea - something similar to the Repository Pattern translates well from OO to Node.js. As for where to put your business logic, I find I sometimes need a "Service" or "Application" layer over my repositories so I can reach into several repositories to compile a complex response. Sometimes you don't need that additional abstraction, so just put it where it's needed - don't get too religious about having layers for business logic - that's N-Tier thinking and it causes a lot of unnecessary code to be written. Add abstractions when they become useful, not as placeholders just in case they are needed - that's a kind of premature optimization.

When we need really high-level business logic, we may need to coordinate the actions of several Microservices. Node.js is your friend here too - you can write lightweight orchestration services that consume messages off an ESB and react to them.

Comment: First off, thank you for your time, it is greatly appreciated.  Starting off, I found myself trying to apply C# principles to node.js and hit alot of square peg - round hole scenarios.  Which led me take a step back to re-evaluate my approach.  So, for a microservices based concept.  Would this be similar to breaking things down into separate domains as in DDD, where each domain in this case would be its own microservice?  If this is the case, I could see it fitting nicely into the scenarios discussed in the book, Patterns, Principles and Practices of domain driven design.

Comment: Microservices should be small than a domain, more like a Bounded Context https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html

Comment: That makes sense.  How did you end up structuring your project folder using node.js?  I have been struggling here as well to find the right folder structure?  Also, when using microservices, are you using seneca.js, I have been reading up on it as well?  For an app. that is really aggregate heavy in one or several bounded contexts, would that be an issue when trying to turn bounded context into microservices?

Comment: I don't spend a lot of time thinking about my project folder structure so I don't have much advice there. I am using Hapi.js since it gives me routing and authentication and then gets out of the way.